# Unable to read repository from Eclipse 3.6

Tags: eclipse, gwt, eclipse-3.6, google-eclipse-plugin, google-plugin-eclipse

Running Eclipse 3.6 and trying to get version 3.2.4 of the GWT plugin.  I add the source and it results in the following:

```
Unable to read repository at https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/eclipse_toolreleases/products/gpe/release/3.2.4/3.6/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/eclipse_toolreleases/products/gpe/release/3.2.4/3.6/content.xml.
com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority, O=Equifax, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
```

I have the correct path, my local time on my machine is accurate/correct (I had read some about some odd timestamp issues with certs?), and I can't seem to find any information about this.  I tried installing locally, and there are missing dependencies when I use a local archive.  I am curious though, why is it trying to hit content.xml? There is no such file in the downloadable repo, and when I try to hit that URI, I get the following:

```
<Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message></Error>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the repository does not have a valid, i.e. trusted, certificate according to our SSL. You need to manually add the certificate as trusted, and then install the plugin.